# Multi indexing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the below [Pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQUIW.jpg). It has two levels of indexing in the columns Segment Name and Variables.

```
                                   mean
seg1  daily_time_spend_on_sight      25
      age                            36
      area_income                  1250
      clicked_on_ad                 250
seg2  daily_time_spend_on_sight      10
      age                            26
      area_income                   950
      clicked_on_ad                 125
```

I need to change the level 0 index to appear in [all the records pertaining to it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4A6Q.jpg)

```
                                   mean
seg1  daily_time_spend_on_sight      25
seg1  age                            36
seg1  area_income                  1250
seg1  clicked_on_ad                 250
seg2  daily_time_spend_on_sight      10
seg2  age                            26
seg2  area_income                   950
seg2  clicked_on_ad                 125
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: `.reset_index()` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dataset like below with multi index you can use `.reset_index()`

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
print(s)
```

```
first  second
bar    one      -0.632949
       two      -1.418744
baz    one      -1.318791
       two       0.194042
foo    one      -0.139960
       two       0.971686
qux    one      -0.257964
       two       1.911748
dtype: float64
```

`s.reset_index()` will give

```
first second         0
0   bar    one -0.632949
1   bar    two -1.418744
2   baz    one -1.318791
3   baz    two  0.194042
4   foo    one -0.139960
5   foo    two  0.971686
6   qux    one -0.257964
7   qux    two  1.911748
```

You can also use `pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False)` i.e

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print(s)
```

Output :

```
first  second
bar    one       1.157404
bar    two      -0.000333
baz    one      -0.774613
baz    two      -1.962658
foo    one       1.337555
foo    two       0.856814
qux    one       0.506146
qux    two       0.755346
dtype: float64
```

For more info about multi indexing you can visit [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

Hope it helps